# iOS strange delegate behavior?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a really strange delegate behavior in iOS. I'm setting a custom delegate in a subclassed UIViewController like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.baseNavigationBar = [[BaseNavigationBar alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.baseNavigationBar.delegate = self;
    self.baseNavigationBar.navigationController = self.navigationController;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.baseNavigationBar];
}
```

The initWithNibName can use nil, when using the default nib, because internally it will check fora nil in the nibName.

```
if (!nibNameOrNil) {
    nibNameOrNil = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}
```

The delegate declaration from the baseNavigationBar object looks the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<BaseNavigationBarDelegate> delegate;
/*same thing with assign, which I you should use*/
/*and in the .m of course @synthesize*/
```

And now 2 screenshots from the running application.

The first one show's the debugger values from the **BaseListViewController**, which is a subclass of **BaseCoreViewController**, which is a subclass of **UIViewController**.

The screenshot is taken, when the viewDidLoad method is called.

[image: List Controller]

The second one show's the values from the **BaseNavigationBar**, which is a **UIView** subclass.

The screenshot is taken at a time, when the user clicks the "next" button

```
- (IBAction)nextAction:(id)sender {
    if (self.delegate) {
        [self.delegate navigationBarDidClickNextButton:self];
    }
}
```

[image: NavigationBar]

So why is this a problem? By clicking a button in the **BaseNavigationBar** my delegate is always nil, so the program is stuck. But when looking at the values from the **BaseCoreViewController** at the same time the delegate is not nil. Very strange.

**Edit**

The BaseNavigationBar is loaded from a nib file using the UINib loadNibNamed:owner:options: function.

**Edit 2**

So that's pretty much all of the code.

**Edit 3**

Finally we got the source of the error in the last pieces of the code... setting self = something totally not allowed...

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

    if (!nibNameOrNil) {
        nibNameOrNil = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    }

    if (!nibBundleOrNil) {
        nibBundleOrNil = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    }

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [nibBundleOrNil loadNibNamed:nibNameOrNil owner:self options:nil];
    /*Here is the bad part*/
    self = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

    state = BaseNavigationBarButtonStateNext;

    if (self) {
        self.title = @"";
    }
    return self;
}
```

Solved using a Class method instead of defining a custom init.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) id<BaseNavigationBarDelegate> delegate;
why retain?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918698/why-are-objective-c-delegates-usually-given-the-property-assign-instead-of-retai

Comment: Doesn't work at all using assign. I don't know why. You're right with "why using retain". I'ss add mode Code quick.

Comment: self.baseNavigationBar property strong? Give more code

Comment: Same behavior using strong. More code coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is. Require some more code to analyze the problem. But what I can see is address of BaseNavigationBar in both the screen shots is different. It means the BaseNavigationBar object present in the controller is not the one which got the nextAction event as in second screen shot.

Comment: You are totally right and I guess I just found the issue. I'll add the init code quick and there you can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using nib file, you should declare the nib class while initialising your class object.

You have initialised `initWithNibName:nil`

```
self.baseNavigationBar = [[BaseNavigationBar alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

but it should be like `initWithNibName:@"BaseNavigationBar"`

```
self.baseNavigationBar = [[BaseNavigationBar alloc] initWithNibName:@"BaseNavigationBar" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: I forgot to mention when passing nil to that inititalizer the function internally calls if (!nibNameOrNil) {
        nibNameOrNil = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    }, so the richt nib gets loaded. I'll add that to the question quick

Comment: Okay!! For delegate you should not set property as retain or strong, you should set property as assign..

Comment: @injections you have mentioned as strong!! Don't set property as strong, set property as assign.

Comment: Same behavior using assign.

Comment: @PrashanthRajagopalan no need to pass your nib name on initWithNibname.Only required nib name when your controller associated with multiple nibs.not sure how up vote....?